# Best way to monitor on/off state with a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, monitor

I have 3D printer with a cooling fan that by design is on constantly, however it only needs to be on when there is something to cool! I have no idea why they have it on all the time since it is loud and wastes power...

So I need to build a circuit that can detect when the heating element is turned on, and then turn on the fan, and turn it back off when the heat is off. I will probably use a PIC for the brains of the circuit (since I want to have a countdown timer and some other functionality) but I am not sure the most efficient way to hook up to the heating element. It is a 24V, 40W heating element with a simple 2 wire lead. I dont want to worry about hooking into the thermocouple, it should just monitor the binary state of the heating element as either on or off (ideally with a 3-5 VDC output that can hook directly to one of the pins of the microcontroller)

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Voltage divider from 24V to 5V, then 10k in series towards the MCU?

Comment: You can use a relay

Comment: @gustavovelascoh Which way would be most efficient with a relay? In series or parallel with the heater?

Comment: Series as you need to switch it on when current is flowing through the heating element.

Answer (score 0):

I think a [optocoupler (opto-isolator)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator) is the way to go. Since there is no physical connection between the 24V and the MCU, when using an optocoupler, the chances you blow up your MCU are way smaller (as example: unknown current/voltage spikes in the 24V line).

Answer (score 0):

You could place a thermodisc near the heating element, and feed the ON/OFF (HEAT/NO HEAT) signal into the control circuit.
Use a "for cooling" model of thermodisc. It could sense air temp or radiant heat.